# A topology on the product space of Euclidean space and smooth functions space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

I'd like to know if there is a well-known topology on the space $S := \mathbb R \times C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, such that $(x_n, f_n) \to (x, f)$ in $S$ with respect the topology is equivalent to 
$$(x_n, f(x_n), f'_n(x_n), f''(x_n)) \to (x, f(x), f'(x), f''(x))$$ 
in Euclidean norm of $\mathbb R^4$?

Indeed, a topology can be simply introduced with a seminorm given by, 
$$\|(x, f)\|_s = |x| + |f(x)| + |f'(x)| + |f''(x)|, \ \forall (x, f) \in \mathbb R \times C^\infty.$$ 
But I'd like to know if such a topology has been studied in some literature?

The motivation of the question is with 
$$F(x, f) := - (- \Delta)^{1/2} f(x) = PV \int_{\mathbb R} (f(x+y) - f(x)) |y|^{-2} dy.$$
It can be shown that $F$ is continuous under the above topology, and I wonder if there is a name.

Comment: Since the values $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are somehow independent, this space then really looks like $\mathbb{R}^4$ and nothing else. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: As @Dirk suggests, there's something amiss in your formulation, since $f(x)$ for a specific numerical argument $x$ is itself just a number. It's hard to guess what you are really wanting: a topology on $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$? The pointwise topology as opposed to the usual Frechet-space topology? Clarify?

Comment: To put Dirk's point another way, such a topology will not be Hausdorff.  For instance if $f(x) = x^3$ then the sequence $(0,0), (0,0), \dots$ converges to $(0,0)$ and also to $(0,f)$.

Comment: As @Dirk, a motivation is added.

Comment: As @paulgarrett says, a motivation is added

Comment: As @NateEldredge says, the topology must not be a Hausdorff. I also made a mistake saying that the norm induced from $\mathbb R^4$ is a norm, and it's corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Your $F$ is not defined for all $f\in C^\infty$ because the integral may not converge for large $y$ (e.g., $f(y) = e^y$). Perhaps you want $f\in C^\infty_c$ or $f\in \mathcal{S}$, that is to have compact support or be Schwartz? Then it's perfectly fine to have the usual test function topology on smooth functions (this is standard in the theory of distributions). Your $F$ is then continuous with respect to the usual Cartesian product topology.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks for your insightful comments. I guess $f\mapsto F(x,f)$ is continuous w.r.t. the test function topology, and $x \to F(x,f)$ is continuous w.r.t. the Euclidean norm. Does it necessarily mean $(x,f) \to F(x,f)$ is continuous to product topology of two?

Comment: In general, no, but you have a very specific $F$ for which you can easily show this. _Exercise_: $E(x,f) = f(x)$ is jointly continuous. Then, you have $F(x,f) = E(x,-(-\Delta)^{1/2}(f))$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks for your answer.